# Typescript cannot find Import path in "baseUrl"

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to not use relative imports in a Node project, by editing some TS config, like this:

```
{
  "baseUrl": ".",
  "paths": {
    "src/*": ["./src/*"]
  }
}
```

So, an import inside 'src/index.ts' file, with the following format should work `import module from 'src/lib/module'`

The module code is basically: `export default { /* code here */ }`

When I run it, it throws an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHAUK.png) saying that it couldn't find the module.
I'm using this script to start the server:

```
"start": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts"
```

Comment: try setting "rootUrl" as well

Comment: Yep, I already did that before. I was messing around with the code, and noticed that only this module.ts file throws an error. Should I edit my post and put actual code in it? @AlexandreDias

Comment: depends, if you dont add neither an export nor an import statement, the file is not considered a module, so you need to be careful when testing something like that